# PhantomJS pdf rendering doesn't load AngularJS routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to render PDF of a web page with a AngularJS app. There are some routing in the app, but PhantomJS doesn't load the UI for the route given.

The url I open in PhantomJS looks like http://domain/something/#/reports/123 which should render the report with the id at the end. But it actually renders http://domain/something/#/reports which is actually report list. Doesn't PhantomJS support AngularJS routing? Or is there a workaround for this? Thanks.

Routing config for ~/reports/123

```
.config(function ( $stateProvider ) {
    $stateProvider.state( 'report-view', {
        url: '/reports/{id:[0-9]{1,12}}',
        controller: 'ReportCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'reports/report/report.tpl.html',
        resolve: {
            settings : ['settingsService', function(settingsService) {
                return settingsService;
            }],
            selectedReport: function(reportServices, $stateParams) {
                return reportServices.getDashboardReportInfo($stateParams.id);
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: What does the routing config look like for `/reports/123`?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're only requesting `/reports/123`? There's no trailing white-space characters after the numbers or anything else that might make it not match `[0-9]{1,12}`

Comment: 100% sure about that one. No spaces

Comment: Try removing the regex requirement from the state URL and see if you get a different result.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work either. Any other thoughts?

Comment: did you solve this @freddy83?

Comment: No I didn't. The solution i went with was to give a seperate angular app to phantomjs without routing, which uses the same directives and services.